# "Session verification failed" while try to exchange token with Yahoo OAuth

Tags: http, oauth, oauth-2.0, http-post, yahoo-oauth

I use Yahoo OAuth 2.0 in my website. Everything's OK in `localhost` tests but when I use this login on my `server`, I got `"Session verification failed"` error while try to exchange the token. I use a trik to login from my localhost with client id, secret id and redirect uri of server app and it's worked. So I don't know what's going on in server.

Exchange token parameters:

```
URL: https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token
Method: POST
Header:
        User-Agent: *
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Host: api.login.yahoo.com
        Content-Length: *
Request body:
        client_id=My_id&client_secret=My_secret&redirect_uri=My_uri&grant_type=authorization_code&code=TheCode
```

Comment: Did you ever find the source of this problem? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: @mmccaff No I didn,t. Currntly I use just google and microsoft login and I disable the yahoo login

Comment: In my case this ending up being that the app's configured callback domain did not match the callback url that I was sending.